# Встроенные средства С++ для работы с бинарной кучей

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Помогите выполнить следующие задачи на С++:

1. Применить встроенные средства языка для перестроения массива в двоичную кучу, добавления произвольного элемента и извлечения максимального элемента из двоичной кучи.
2. Применить встроенные средства языка для сортировки пирамидой.

Эти алгоритмы у меня уже реализованы на голом С++, а вот какими стандартными средствами располагает язык для этих задач, я не знаю, и гугл ничего не находит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это следующие алгоритмы для работы с кучей, объявленные в заголовке `<algorithm>`:

1. `make_heap()` преобразует диапазон элементов в кучу.
2. `push_heap()` добавляет один элемент в кучу.
3. `pop_heap()` удаляет следующий элемент из кучи.
4. `sort_heap()` преобразует кучу в сортированную коллекцию, после чего куча уже не является кучей.
5. `is_heap()` проверяет, является ли диапазон элементов кучей.